# Pig Spawner Underground?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Im saving up for a pig spawner in factions and im about to have it, so I was wondering if it would work underground, With the right conditions.

Comment: Are you referring to a specific server?

Comment: What do you mean by "right conditions"? Grassed area above `y=60` that is lit (but is caved/enclosed and does not have vision of the sky)?

Comment: Yes. That is what I meant

Comment: So does it need to be above a certain y value or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pig Spawners work everywhere if there is grass where pigs can spawn in the 8x8 radius from spawner.

Comment: They need light as well I believe, but torchlight works just as well as daylight.

Comment: So does it need to be above a certain y value or not?

Comment: You haven't to be at certain y level.